# What are the numbers in var_dump result?

Tags: php, var-dump

What do the numbers #11 and (0) mean in this `var_dump` result:

> object(PDO)#11 (0) { }

I have a class and I made from it an object and used it in multiple places.

Comment: `#n` typically refers to [resource handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831364/what-are-resources) (sockets or file pointers)

Comment: "I have a class and I made from it an object and used it in multiple places." - I think you mean you have an `object` you created from a `class`. A `class` is like an object's blueprints, and an `object` is an *instance* of a class, i.e. a collection of data inside a running program. (Think about how the USS Enterprise NCC-1701-D is a *Galaxy class* starship: the class is "Galaxy" and the object-name is "Enterprise").

Comment: @mario Indeed, `#n` is the "handle" of an object **or** a resource. In the OP's case, `PDO` is an actual PHP `object` from a PHP `class` instead of it being a "resource" directly (though `PDO` does wrap resources, of course).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know either, so let's find out together, [by looking at the source-code for `var_dump`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/500b4b4945e3768afd2cfcae61548ef47e7f003f/ext/standard/var.c)! (look for `PHP_FUNCTION(var_dump)`).

(For TL;DR, jump to the end)

1. The PHP function `var_dump` is a wrapper for the C function `php_var_dump`.
2. `php_var_dump` has a `switch()` statement to generate different output for each of PHP's basic types (numbers, strings, booleans, objects, etc), and we're interested in the `object` type.
3. Within the `case IS_OBJECT:` case we see this:

   ```
   php_printf("%sobject(%s)#%d (%d) {\n", COMMON, ZSTR_VAL(class_name), Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(struc), myht ? zend_array_count(myht) : 0);
   ```
4. The `#10` in your output comes from the `#%d` part of the format-string, which is the 3rd C variadic arg, and the `(0)` is the 4th C variadic arg.

   - the 3rd is `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(struc)`
   - the 4th is `myht ? zend_array_count(myht) : 0`
5. `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P` basically returns a unique identifier for an object in PHP (so your PDO instance is the 11th object <sub>(I think, see below)</sub> created in the processing of this request).
6. The `myht` thing is more complicated: but if it's set it means you asked PHP to `var_dump` an `object` member property (rather than an object itself), e.g. `var_dump( $foo->bar )` instead of `var_dump( $foo )`. If you aren't referring to an object-property then it just prints `0`.

---

#### Regarding how `->handle` values are determined and what they mean:

- The `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P` macro is  `Z_OBJ_HANDLE(*(zval_p))`

  - The `Z_OBJ_HANDLE` macro is `(Z_OBJ((zval)))->handle`
  - The `Z_OBJ` macro is `(zval).value.obj`
  - So `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_P(x)` is the same as `x.value.obj->handle`
- Note that instances of user-defined classes and PHP "resources" are both "objects" and both have a `uint32 handle` member (but implemented separately).

  - You can see this if you compare `_zend_object` with `_zend_resource` in [zend_types.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/353f7ffb6b3f6e7c3aed8b3ed51182a973e120b8/Zend/zend_types.h)
- For "resources" (built-in objects provided by the PHP environment), PHP maintains a list of resources in an execution environment. When a new resource is created it's added to the list by `zend_list_insert` (which then uses the `ZVAL_NEW_RES` macro). The `->handle` value is the index into that list (though I'm unsure if it starts at `0` or `1` or some other base).
- For PHP `class` objects ("user types", etc), the `zend_objects_store_put` function is used which adds the object to the `objects_store` list and returns the the index of the item in the list (so it's conceptually similar to `zend_list_insert`).

  - Again, I don't know what the initial or base value is (e.g. `0`, `1`, or something else).

---

## TL;DR:

So `object(PDO)#11 (0) { }` means:

- the object is an instance of the `PDO` class.
- the object is the 11th <sub>(probably)</sub> object created during the processing of the current HTTP request.
- the object is its own top-level object rather than an object property reference.